How can I use the user logged in tEdge to login to React Application?
I want to retrieve the user from the AAD account on Edge to authenticate my React application using msal.
The msal documentation provides information for how to do a login from scratch. However, Edge already is authenticated and has the username and the email. I would like to retrieve this information so that I can perform a silent login using msalInstance.ssoSilent()
I have tried to get the account with instance.getAllAccounts() but that doesn't seem to be connected to the browser accounts

I'm afraid you can't retrieve the browser logged-in accounts. The library is not meant to interact with browser itself, but with the web applications.
Maybe you should consider one of the Browser to Web Single Sign-On (SSO) approaches. For more information, please read Browser to Web Single Sign-On (SSO).
